# LibGDX: How to keep an Object at same visual screen position while rotating the camera

Tags: math, 3d, libgdx, google-cardboard

I have a 3D, Y-up world and a Perspective Camera.
When I start my world, my camera is at position (0,2,0) looking at (0,0,1).
Now I place a 3D Model at (10,5,10). (Let it be a cube)

What needs to be done (translation, rotation,...) to keep this object at visually the same position when I start rotating the camera around the 3 axes or even translate/move it ?

What would further be necessary if I want to be able to change the model's position but keep the distance of the model to the camera the same ?

What I want to achieve is an object where I can display the current highscore of the player and regardless where the player looks at, it will always be for example in the top right corner. In a normal application I could use Scene2D for that, but as I am developing for Google's Cardboard, Scene2D does not work anymore. (Because we have two different perspective view settings for each eye and these can't be used for the OrthographicCamera of the Stage).

Answer (score 0):

So what you're trying to do here can be done mathematically by giving the cube a transform that is relative to the camera's transform- essentially making the camera the origin as far as your cube is concerned.

However, if I may suggest a better way- you could create a separate `PerspectiveCamera` which stays at the origin (or wherever) and is responsible for rendering the UI separately from the rest of your game. It uses the same principle as Scene2D, but is less complicated and makes it easier to switch out your UI later if you're not supporting Google Cardboard.

Comment: Your second approach seems to be the right way forward. I get it the UI Panel displayed "statically" but now of the problem that it gets cut off by the floor layer, which looks pretty funny when i nod the camera up and down. How can I tell openGL to handle the second drawing step separately from the first one ?